# Big-O complexity of recursion with nested loops

Tags: java, big-o, complexity-theory

Preparing for exams I came across this question in an old exam:

What is the worst case/big-O complexity of this function:

```
float foo(float[] A) {
    int n = A.length;
    if (n == 1) return A[0];
    float[] A1 = new float[n/2];
    float[] A2 = new float[n/2];
    float[] A3 = new float[n/2];
    float[] A4 = new float[n/2];

    for (i = 0; i <= (n/2)-1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= (n/2)-1; j++) {
            A1[i] = A[i];
            A2[i] = A[i+j];
            A3[i] = A[n/2+j];
            A4[i] = A[j];
        }
    }

    return foo(A1)
         + foo(A2)
         + foo(A3)
         + foo(A4);
}
```

(Yes, the code makes no sense, but this is exactly the way it was written).

What's tripping me up is that the total size of n doubles for each recursive level, but the suggested answer(with the end result `O(log n * n^2)`) ignores that part. Am I misunderstanding things?

Edit: Replaced the semi-pseudocode with syntactically correct(but still nonsensical) code.

Comment: What does the function return?

Comment: It doesn't return anything. It's just a nonsense function for a theoretical exam question.

Answer (score 2):

If you solve this recursive relation, you'd be able to determine the complexity.

```
T(n) = 4T(n/2) + O(n²)
```

With

```
T(1) = c
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I finally figured it out.

Every time we recurse we do 4 times as many function calls as last time, so if we define the recursion level as `m` the number of function calls per level is

[image: 4^m]

Every time we recurse we also halve the size of the array, so the amount of work per function call is

[image: (n / 2^m)^2]

At each recursive level the work done in total then is:

[image: 4^m * (n / 2^m)^2]

In fact `4^m` is the same as `(2^m)^2`:

[image: 4^m = (2^2)^m = 2^2m = (2^m)^2]

Thus the amount of work can be written as just `n^2`:

[image: 4^m * (n / 2^m)^2 = (2^m * (n / (2^m))^2 = n^2]

There are `log n` recursive levels.

**Thus the total amount of work is `O(n^2 * log n)`, and that is *because* there are 4 recursive calls.**

If there were just 2 recursive calls the amount of work at each level would be

[image: 2^m * (n / 2^m)^2]

which we can't reduce nicely(but turns out to be in `O(n^2)` if my math is correct).